# Angular 2 : increment *ngFor by 2 or implementing two paginations with in a Pagination

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template, ngfor

I am pretty new to Angular and I was wondering if there is any way to increment the ngFor loop by 2 instead of 1.

I am trying to implement two pagination's with in a pagination for which increment the loop by 2 is required.

I am getting objects which have objects with in. Lets say users and list of their address.

(First NgFor is to paginate the users by 2. If I get 15 users. 2 users will be displayed in one page)

```
li *ngFor="let user of Users | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 1, currentPage: p };let i = index"
{{user[i].firstName}} <--Displaying first userName-->
```

(Second NgFor is to display list of address of the first user. Lets say he has 20 address. I will be slicing it to 3 or 4 per page and paginate the rest)

```
 *ngFor="let address of user[i].address| objectValues |slice:addresspageNumber*2-2:addressPageNumber*5 ; let j = index "
<--First child Pagination code-->

 {{user[i+1].firstName}}  <--Displaying second userName-->
```

(Third NgFor is to display list of address of the second user. Lets say he has 20 address. I will be slicing it to 3 or 4 per page and paginate the rest)

```
 *ngFor="let address of user[i+1].address| objectValues |slice:addresspageNumber*2-2:addressPageNumber*5 ; let j = index ">
<th scope="row">{{address.streetno}}
<--Second child Pagination code-->

<--Parent Pagination code-->
```

Now if I dont increment the first ngFor by two, in the next page the second user will be displayed again which I dont want to.

I either have to increment by 2 or implement pagination seperately for two childs which I cant do it in one for loop

All I want is two separate pagination's to be implemented with in one pagination

Object1.name
                             object1.address.street
                             object1.address.pin
                             -- pagination to display other address.

Object2.name
                             object2.address.street
                             object2.address.pin
                             -- second pagination to display other address.
--main pagination which on click will show two more object details

Answer (score 6):

For increment by 2

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let even = even;">
  <div *ngIf="even">
    // content
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can increment `*ngFor` by 2 because it's purpose is to display an array-kind data; plus I don't really understand your requirements.

However you can use `*ngIf` in a combination with `%` operator in order to not react on every second entry.

This could do the job

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <span *ngIf="i % 2 === 0"> // or <ng-template if it is better here>
```

The same effect could be achieved for any iteration size. Just replace the `2` with e.g. `10` to increment by 10.

Comment: You can also use [ngSwitch} if things get more complex. An example is here:  https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/directives/ng_switch_directives.html

Comment: @JGFMK it does not make any sense here... Does it?

Comment: Not for this particular use case.. But I was thinking of others who would come to thread later, with similar problems, that needed 3 or more variations... maybe re-rendering header, header+ description, header+description+narrative etc...

Comment: *ngIf="i % 2 === 0 would not help because I want to display both the records in that page.
with this condition, page two will not display any records and page 3 will display two records like one.

Comment: All I want is two separate pagination's to be implemented with in one pagination 


Object1.name
                             object1.address.street
                             object1.address.pin
                             -- pagination to display other address.

Object2.name
                             object2.address.street
                             object2.address.pin
                             -- second pagination to display other address.
--main pagination which on click will show two more object details