# Angular 2 ngFor on the same tr element

Tags: angular, iterator, ngfor

Value of cList is :

```
code value1 value2
ABC  01     test1
DEF  02     test2
GHI  03     test3
JKL  04     test4
MNO  05     test5
PQR  06     test6
STU  07     test7
VWX  08     test8
```

my component.ts has the foll. arraylist. 1st 4 list is added to cList1 and 5-8 added to cList4.

```
cList: CaseInventorySummaryCustomDTO[] = [];
cList1: CaseInventorySummaryCustomDTO[] = [];
cList2: CaseInventorySummaryCustomDTO[] = [];

this.cList = this.data.cList;
for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {                  
    this.cList1.push(this.cList[i]);
}
for (let i = 4; i < this.cList.length; i++) { 
    this.cList2.push(this.cList[i]);
}
```

my component.html is as follows:

```
<table>
<thead colspan="12">
    Subject Specialities
</thead>
<tr *ngFor="let i of cList1; let j of cList2">
    <td style="width: 4em">
       {{i.code}}
    </td>
    <td style="width: 3em">
        {{i.value1}}
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        {{i.value2}}
    </td>
    <td style="width: 4em">
        {{j.code}}
    </td>
    <td style="width: 3em">
        {{j.value1}}
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        {{j.value2}}
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My expected output is

```
    Subject Specialities
ABC 01  test1   MNO 05  test5
DEF 02  test2   PQR 06  test6
GHI 03  test4   STU 07  test7
JKL 04  test4   VWX 08  test8
```

But what i see is,

```
    Subject Specialities
MNO 05  test5   MNO 05  test5
PQR 06  test6   PQR 06  test6
STU 07  test7   STU 07  test7
VWX 08  test8   VWX 08  test8
```

Does 2 ngFor not work on the same tr? or Am i wrong with the above code? Can someone please help.

Comment: You can't iterate two arrays in a single `*ngFor`. They need to be split among two `<tr>` tags.

Comment: I cannot split into 2 tr since the value 2 can be a big paragraph sometimes. So that tr appear to look huge and the other tr small. Is there any work around for the same?

Comment: @JNPW, you can not use `let i of cList1; let j of cList2` use `let i of cList1; let index=index` and inside the loop `cList2[index]` instead "j"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do the loop 2 arrays in one `*ngFor`.
You can use the element [`<ng-container>`](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue) for the second loop.

> The Angular `<ng-container>` is a grouping element that doesn't interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the DOM.

```
<tr *ngFor="let i of cList1;">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let j of cList2">
    ...
  </ng-container>
</tr>
```

---

### Solution for question

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of cList1; let i = index">
    <td style="width: 4em">
       {{i.code}}
    </td>
    <td style="width: 3em">
        {{i.value1}}
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        {{i.value2}}
    </td>
    <td style="width: 4em">
        {{cList2[i].code}}
    </td>
    <td style="width: 3em">
        {{cList2[i].value1}}
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        {{cList2[i].value2}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I tried this. But ng-container behves like an inner ngfor. So what is happening is for each outer forloop the inner for loop executes 4 times since it has 4 values in the list. so 1st row will have 8 values in the list ...this is repeating for all 4 rows in the outer loop

Comment: if you are sure to have the same length for both cList1 and cList2, loop only one with indexing, like `*ngFor="let item of cList1; let i = index"` and to indicate cList2 items, use cList2[i].code

Comment: even though both array lengths are different, you can just check before using cList2[i].code

Comment: critically, if you don't know the both array length, then you can do ngFor like `*ngFor="let in of math.max(cList1.length, cList2.length); let i = index"`

Comment: So I just tried <tr *ngFor="let item of cList1; let i = index"> and tried {{item.code}}, {{item.value1}}, {{item.value2}} for 1st 3 td and {{cList[i].code}}, {{cList[i].value1}} and {{cList[i].value2}} for last 3 td's but still not getting proper values. I see ABC 01 test1 ABC 01 test2 in the 1st row and DEF repeats on 2nd tr and so on...

Comment: there is a typo to indicate second array - `cList2`

Comment: i updated answer with the solution for your question.

Comment: is it possible to increment he index by 2 by any chance?

Comment: i don't think so. check this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176953/angular-2-increment-ngfor-by-2-or-implementing-two-paginations-with-in-a-pagi