# Angular: *ngFor set iterator size

Tags: angular, for-loop, angular-forms

I'm trying to do a for loop in angular, i know how it works `*ngFor="let item of items;let i = index"` 
But how can I say that I want my index to do +2 increment, so i would be 0,2,4,6...
How can I do that please ?

The equivalent in C

```
for(int i=0;i<=100;i+=2)
{
  my code;
}
```

`items` is a list of all my items, lets say that in my for loop I just displat my `item`, what i wanna do with that for loop is to print the first item, the third, the fifth ...

I tried in my html page to use this syntax `item[index].whatever` but it doesn"t work :'(

Please help

Thanks

Comment: i think some answers from here might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176953/angular-2-increment-ngfor-by-2-or-implementing-two-paginations-with-in-a-pagi

Comment: You could implement a custom structural directive to do this.
Here's an example that may help: 
https://www.netjstech.com/2021/07/create-custom-structural-directive-angular.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display index of 0,2,4,6...

```
   <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
            <span *ngIf="i % 2 === 0">Index: {{i}}</span>
   </div>
```

If you want to display index of 1,3,5,7...

```
   <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
            <span *ngIf="i % 2 !== 0">Index: {{i}}</span>
   </div>
```